# How do I continue scraping data when the site detects unusual traffic?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I was trying to make a web crawler for fun and I ran into a dilemma. I found a site in chinese with some interesting data and decided to make a bot that would: 1) request the url of the site, 2) adjust that URL incremetally to go to a different page, 3) search the DOM and find where the the thumbnail image is held, and 5) save the thumbnail image to my desktop.I made two if else statement nested within each other that would catch the times when the webpage either: doesn't exist or doesn't have a thumbnail image and thus doesn't have the class that image would be located in. If either of those things happen it would print the page number where the thumbnail was not save to my computer and continue.

The problem comes when, after I ran the code for a while, it stopped saving the images to my computer even when there is a thumbnail in that location. I think this might be due to the website noticing my attempts to get the data since i'm getting a "unusual traffic detected" warning. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
from pickle import NONE
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


localfile = "C:/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/Chinese Games/"
url = "https://www.9game.cn/xiazai/" 


for x in range(1, 500):
        page = requests.get(url + str(x) + "/")         # Request url and iterate with x 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml') 
        image = soup.find(class_="d-headgame-icon")     # Finds the HTML elements that holds the image 
        if image != None:                           
            result = image.find("img").attrs['src']     # Extracts the URL of the image from all other elements
            if result !="":
                title = image.find("img").attrs['alt']  # Extracts the name of the image from all other elements
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(result, localfile + title + ".jpg")  # Saves images to Desktop as a JPG file
            else:
                print(x)    # Prints the page number if there is no image
        else:
            print(x)        # Prints the page number if there is no image
```

Comment: It is seen as an attack for good reason, because you are not just impersonating a real user with your crawler, you're also attempting to harvest unlinked content and making an unusual number of requests to non-existent URLs. Any decent Web Application Firewall is going to lock your app out eventually.

Comment: This is like asking how to get into a building when the people who live there keep telling you they don't want you there - depending on where the server is, that may be illegal or just unethical, but it certainly isn't something you should expect to be the norm. Have you checked if this site offers an API, or some other means of accessing the same data?

Comment: I addition to the valid points above: You just bombard the site with 500 requests in a very short time. Whenever I do something similiar I (1) check if there's a robots.txt and if so what it says, (2) use `time.sleep(1)` etc. for inserting a small timeout that reduces the burden on the site.